# Connect Wolfram Mathematica to Unity

Tags: external-calls

My question is how to connect Wolfram Mathematica with Unity.

Following the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574542/cant-open-unity-link-in-wolfram-mathematica, I get an error when i try to create `UnityLink`

```
Needs["UnityLink`"]
```

[image]

I installed Wolfram Engine and tried almost all possible ways to run the Wolfram code in Unity.
I saw a video where a guy create some wolfram.unitypackage somehow!

Please, explain me in a plain English, how to set it up ?